# EF Migration CLI creates incorrect column data types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

In [part 4 of the ASP.NET Core MVC tutorial for Visual Studio code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#initial-migration), the EF migrations cli command of

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

is producing a migration file with incorrect column data types.

After running `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`, the command should have taken the following `Movie.cs` class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcMovie.Models;

public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string? Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And the expected output should have been a migration file `Migrations/{time-stamp}_InitialCreate.cs`, with the following content:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace MvcMovie.Migrations
{
    public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Movie",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    ReleaseDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                    Genre = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Price = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18,2)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Movie", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Movie");
        }
    }
}
```

The actual output was:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace MvcMovie.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Movie",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    ReleaseDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    Genre = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    Price = table.Column<decimal>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Movie", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Movie");
        }
    }
}
```

As can be seen above, some properties like `Price`, produces a column of type `TEXT` instead of `decimal(18,2)`.

Comment: SQLite and Sql Server are two different DBMS. | SQLite has no decimal type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your autoincrement specification, it appears you are using SQLite - this does not support a decimal type, so it will fall back to using `TEXT`.